# Want to create new table comparing two table using stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures

i have three table

1) first table->illnessarea

```
   ID Area
   1  Heart
   2  Ear
```

2) Second table ->Specialisation

```
   ID  Specialisation
   12  Cardiovascular
```

3) Temp Table

```
  Areaname   Specialisationname
  Heart      Cardiovascular
```

Want new table using stored procedure

```
 AreaId SpecializationID
 1      12
```

I am not much exp in Stored procedure.
Help Me

Comment: please add your table structure @swati

Comment: i updated the question